# I always get a 500 POST and PUT error, but i can edit or update my users but still i get an error to my put. I use a blazor wasm using foreign key

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I always get a 500 POST and PUT error, but i can edit or update my users but still i get an error to my put.  I use a blazor wasm using foreign key
here's my code

```
  namespace EmployeeMaster.Shared
    {
     public class Employee
         {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeNo { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string MiddleName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string NickName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int TelePhone { get; set; }
    public double MobilePhone { get; set; }
    public int ReligionId { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string BloodType { get; set; } = string.Empty;        
    public Division? Division { get; set; }
    public int? DivisionId { get; set; }
    public Department? Department { get; set; }
    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }

}
```

}

namespace EmployeeMaster.Shared
{
public class Gender
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
}

```
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DivisionId { get; set; }
    public Division Division { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
  public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

}

```
  namespace EmployeeMaster.Server.Data
    {
public class EmployeeMasterServerContext : DbContext
{
    public EmployeeMasterServerContext(DbContextOptions<EmployeeMasterServerContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
        .HasOne(d => d.Division)
        .WithMany(d => d.Departments)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.DivisionId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction); ;

      modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
        .HasOne(e => e.Department)
        .WithMany(d => d.Employees)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.DepartmentId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Division>().HasData(
             new Division { Id = 1, DivisionId = 1, Name = "FAMS" },
             new Division { Id = 2, DivisionId = 2, Name = "LOG" },
             new Division { Id = 3, DivisionId = 3, Name = "SOD" },
             new Division { Id = 4, DivisionId = 4, Name = "CAD" },
             new Division { Id = 5, DivisionId = 5, Name = "AGRO" }
            )
            ;
        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().HasData(
             new Department { Id = 1, Name = "IT", DivisionId = 1 },
             new Department { Id = 2, Name = "OPD", DivisionId = 1 },
             new Department { Id = 3, Name = "CNC", DivisionId = 1 },
             new Department { Id = 4, Name = "Cashier", DivisionId = 1 },
             new Department { Id = 5, Name = "Accounting", DivisionId = 1 },
             new Department { Id = 6, Name = "IPPR", DivisionId = 2 },
             new Department { Id = 7, Name = "Transport", DivisionId = 2 },
             new Department { Id = 8, Name = "Supply Chain", DivisionId = 2 },
             new Department { Id = 9, Name = "Sonic 1", DivisionId = 3 },
             new Department { Id = 10, Name = "Sonic 2", DivisionId = 3 },
             new Department { Id = 11, Name = "Sonic 3", DivisionId = 3 },
             new Department { Id = 12, Name = "UFS", DivisionId = 3 },
             new Department { Id = 13, Name = "URIC", DivisionId = 3 },
             new Department { Id = 14, Name = "HR", DivisionId = 4 },
             new Department { Id = 15, Name = "SSHE", DivisionId = 4 },
             new Department { Id = 16, Name = "OPD", DivisionId = 5 },
             new Department { Id = 17, Name = "Transport", DivisionId = 5 },
             new Department { Id = 18, Name = "Supply Chain", DivisionId = 5 }
         );

    }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Division> Divisions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}
 }


   namespace EmployeeMaster.Server.Controllers
 {
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EmployeeMasterController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly EmployeeMasterServerContext _context;

    public EmployeeMasterController(EmployeeMasterServerContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<Employee>>>GetEmployeeModel()
    {  
        var EmployeeModels= await _context.Employee
            .Include(sh => sh.Division)
            .ToListAsync();

        return Ok(EmployeeModels);
    }

    [HttpGet("division")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<Division>>> GetDivision()
    {
        var Divisions= await _context.Divisions.ToListAsync();
        return Ok(Divisions);
    }



    [HttpGet("department")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<Department>>> GetDepartment(int? divisionId)
    {
        if (divisionId == null)
        {
            return await _context.Departments.ToListAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            return await _context.Departments.Where(d => d.DivisionId ==            divisionId).ToListAsync();
        }
    }


    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Employee>> GetSingleEmployee(int id)
    {
        var user = await _context.Employee
            .Include(h => h.Division)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(h=>h.Id==id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound("sorry no users here");
        }
        return Ok(user);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<Employee>>> CreateEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        if (employee.DivisionId == 0)
        {
            employee.Division = null;
        }

            _context.Employee.Add(employee);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        
 
        return Ok(await GetDBEmployees());
    }


    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<Employee>>> UpdateEmployee(Employee employee, int id)
    {
        if (employee == null || id != employee.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var dbEmployee = await _context.Employee
            .Include(h => h.Division)
            .Include(h => h.Department)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(h => h.Id == id);
            if (dbEmployee == null)
                return NotFound("sorry no user for you");
        if (employee.DivisionId == 0)
        {
            dbEmployee.Division = null;
        }
        else
        {
            dbEmployee.DivisionId = employee.DivisionId;
        }
            dbEmployee.EmployeeNo = employee.EmployeeNo;
            dbEmployee.StatusId = employee.StatusId;
            dbEmployee.FirstName = employee.FirstName;
            dbEmployee.LastName = employee.LastName;
            dbEmployee.MiddleName = employee.MiddleName;
            dbEmployee.NickName = employee.NickName;
            dbEmployee.Height = employee.Height;
            dbEmployee.Weight = employee.Weight;
            dbEmployee.Email = employee.Email;
            dbEmployee.TelePhone = employee.TelePhone;
            dbEmployee.MobilePhone = employee.MobilePhone;
            dbEmployee.ReligionId = employee.ReligionId;
            dbEmployee.Nationality = employee.Nationality;
            dbEmployee.GenderId = employee.GenderId;
            dbEmployee.BloodType = employee.BloodType;
            dbEmployee.DivisionId = employee.DivisionId;
            dbEmployee.DepartmentId = employee.DepartmentId;

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     
        return Ok(await GetDBEmployees());
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<Employee>>> DeleteEmployee(int id)
    {
        var dbEmployee = await _context.Employee.Include(h => h.Division).Include(h => h.Genders).Include(h => h.Status).Include(h => h.CivilStatus).Include(sh => sh.Religion).Include(sh => sh.Division.Departments)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(h => h.Id == id);
        if (dbEmployee == null)
            return NotFound("sorry no user for you");

        _context.Employee.Remove(dbEmployee);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok(await GetDBEmployees());
    }

    private async Task<List<Employee>> GetDBEmployees()
    {
        return await _context.Employee
            .Include(sh=> sh.Division)
            .Include(h => h.Department)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
}
   }



  namespace EmployeeMaster.Client.Services.EmployeeService
  {
public class EmployeeModelService : IEmployeeModelService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _http;
    private readonly NavigationManager _navigationManager;

    public EmployeeModelService(HttpClient http, NavigationManager navigationManager)
    {
        _http = http;
        _navigationManager = navigationManager;
    }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }= new List<Employee>();
    public List<Division> Divisions { get; set; } = new List<Division>();
    public List<Department> Departments { get; set; } = new List<Department>();

    public async Task CreateEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Saving Services");
            var result = await _http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/EmployeeMaster", employee);
            await SetEmployees(result);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
      
    }

    private async Task SetEmployees(HttpResponseMessage result)
    {

        var response = await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<Employee>>();
        Employees = response;
    }

    public async Task DeleteEmployee(int id)
    {
        var result = await _http.DeleteAsync($"api/EmployeeMaster/{id}");
        await SetEmployees(result);
    }

    public async Task GetDivisions()
    {
        var result = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Division>>("api/EmployeeMaster/division");
        if (result != null)
            Divisions = result;
    }

    public async Task GetEmployee()
    {
        var result = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Employee>>("api/EmployeeMaster");
        if(result !=null)
            Employees= result;
    }

    public async Task<Employee> GetSingleEmployee(int id)
    {
        var result = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<Employee>($"api/EmployeeMaster/{id}");
        if (result != null)
            return result;
        throw new Exception("employee not found");
    }
    public async Task UpdateEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        var result = await _http.PutAsJsonAsync($"api/EmployeeMaster/{employee.Id}", employee);
        await SetEmployees(result);
    }


    public async Task GetDepartments()
    {
        var result = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Department>>("api/EmployeeMaster/department");
        if (result != null)
            Departments = result;
    }
}
```

}

I tried to check my api but i still get an error.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: PUT https://localhost:44392/api/EmployeeMaster/4 500                                                          POST https://localhost:44392/api/EmployeeMaster/4 500                                                        when i create or update, thats the error i am getting

Comment: 500 is usally internal Server Error. This means it is on the Server Side. Try setting a breakpoint and debug what the real Error is.

Comment: when i use a breakpoint. the error is in api